# Does BigTable allow setting micro timestamp granularity

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to write a cell to Bigtable with timestamp as micro granularity. The doc over here says that i should be able to set the granularity to micros: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/data/rpc/google.bigtable.v2#google.bigtable.v2.Mutation.SetCell

But if you look at the java client, i dont see an option to set it other than millis. https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/admin/rpc/google.bigtable.admin.v2#google.bigtable.admin.v2.Table.TimestampGranularity

Same for Ruby client
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-bigtable/lib/google/cloud/bigtable/instance.rb#L548

Does anyone know if it is possible to set the granularity to micros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached out to google and they confirmed that they only support setting cell timestamp by millis granularity even though the timestamp internally seems to be stored as micros.

This is what their C++ library says

> Cloud Bigtable currently supports only millisecond granularity in the
>   cell timestamps, both TIMESTAMP_GRANULARITY_UNSPECIFIED and MILLIS
>   have the same effect. Creating cells with higher granularity than the
>   supported value is rejected by the server.

https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-cpp/latest/bigtable/classgoogle_1_1cloud_1_1bigtable_1_1v1_1_1TableConfig.html#a4ee0e2162c04b1e67bbac98605d165fd

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the [Google API Documentation](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-bigtable/latest/Google/Cloud/Bigtable/Table.html#granularity-instance_method):

> If unspecified at creation time, the value will be set to MILLIS

It seems that you need to set the granularity when creating your BigTable to micros, unless, it will be set to default to milliseconds. Besides that, as mentioned in the [Package google.bigtable.v2](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/data/rpc/google.bigtable.v2) documentation, there is the function `TimestampRangeFilterMicros` that you can use with values in micros - more information in this BigTable documentation [here](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigtable).

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: The question is about how to specify the timestamp granularity during the table creation, and this answer doesn't cover that topic.